# thread lock in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, locking

I code a python script using a gstreamer plugin. 
It returns me a segmentation fault because a race to access to a shared file (which one thread writes and the gstremear one createsreads) happens. 
I wanna lock it during the writing phase, reading the Python doc.
I coded in the `__init__`:

```
self.lock=thread.allocate_lock()
```

and then in another function in the same class of `__init__`:

```
self.lock.acquire()
try:
    plt.savefig(self.filepath_image,transparent=True)
finally:
    self.lock.release()
```

Comment: Are both of the threads calling acquire() on the lock at the appropriate times?  (Having only one thread use the lock wouldn't stop the other thread from messing with the file during the critical period, they have to both acquire it so that the second one will be blocked inside acquire() until the first one calls release())

Comment: What kind of suggestions? Is it still segfaulting or are you asking if that's a proper way of doing this?

Comment: @bereal if it's the proper way to do this

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Yep, in effect I use just to one thread, beacuse I cannot modify the gstreamer code.

Comment: If you can't find some way to get the gstreamer code to wait on your lock at the appropriate times, then having just your own thread acquiring and releasing the lock won't change anything  :(

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Yeah, comforting.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, if I understand your situation correct, you may want to make the `savefig` operation atomic, which can be done like this:

```
import os, shutil, tempfile    

tempfile = os.path.join(tempfile.tempdir, self.filepath_image)
#          ^^^ or simply self.filepath_image + '.tmp'
try:
    plt.savefig(tempfile,transparent=True)     # draw somewhere else 
    shutil.move(tempfile, self.filepath_image) # move to the target
finally:
    if os.path.exists(tempfile):
        os.remove(tempfile)
```

`shutil.move` is atomic (at least, in Unix, inside the same FS), so nobody will access the destination file until it's ready for usage.

Comment: yeah, I read about this stuff, using "os.rename(tmp,self.filepath_imagae)", but the error is not worked out.
I'll try your method and I'll keep you up.

Comment: @FrankBr Well, `os.rename` is the same in this case, so if it does not work this won't either. Are you sure that this file access is a root cause?

Comment: I suppose because I have no further evidences about the segfault.

Comment: Well, if you first save that picture the same way and then comment out all the the `savefig` code, will it be still segfaulting?

Comment: No, because that the problem is when I show it in overlay during a video play, feature done thanks to gstreamer which use another thread to do this. The problem I think is related to the fact that while the gst plugin access to a file, sometimes also the 'savefig' it's exectuted at the same time! So, I would like to get a lock, to do those ops in two different moment.